# display multiple OpenCV imshow() windows separately

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have a VS console application that is built using opencv library. I am displaying image using the opencv imshow function. The thing is that all the imshow windows overlap over each other and it is difficult to toggle between them.  How can I prevent the overlap and display them separately and toggle between them

Answer (score 3):

The way to go about this programatically, is to call [`resizeWindow()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#resizewindow) to define each windows' size and [`moveWindow()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow) to place them at specific locations in your screen.

```
void cv::resizeWindow(const string& winname, int width, int height)
void cv::moveWindow(const string& winname, int x, int y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this is a late reply, you may find it useful to call **moveWindow()** after each **imshow()** call. A **language independent** solution is given here.

Example steps :-

> 1. call **imshow("first image", img1)**

> 2. call **moveWindow("first image", img1, 0, 0)** //*Default position of window is at col,row == 0,0. So, this line is optional.*
> 3. call **imshow("second image", img2)**
> 4. set firstImageWidth = width of img1
> 5. set mySpacing = 40 //vary this to increase/decrease the gap between the image windows.
> 6. call **moveWindow("first image", firstImageWidth + mySpacing , 0)**

Then, add these lines to prevent output windows from being forever active.

> 1. set **myTime = 7000** //in milliseconds. Here, 7000 ms == 7 secs to show our image windows.
> 2. call **waitKey(myTime)**
> 3. call **waitKey(1)**  //this is a trick. Otherwise, the windows are opened indefinitely.

At the moment, I am using Java SE8 with OpenCV 4.2. The above method works for me.
[Screenshot of the above example in action.][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaTI0.png

Here is a Java+OpenCV code snippet for the display part:

> **...**
> //display image. Using OpenCV HighGui class methods.
> String inputWindowName = "This window shows input image";
> String outputWindowName = "This window shows output image";

> HighGui displayWindow = new HighGui();

> displayWindow.imshow(inputWindowName, img1);

> displayWindow.imshow(outputWindowName, img2);
> displayWindow.moveWindow(outputWindowName,  img1.cols()+40, 0);

> displayWindow.waitKey(7000);
> displayWindow.waitKey(1);